# Como passar items de listView para texto

Tags: vb.net, listview, visual-basic-6, textbox

Tenho uma listView com alguns itens e colunas, gostaria de saber como passar tudo para uma textBox, em forma de texto mesmo.
Exemplo:

**A tabela:**

```
ID    NOME    IDADE
0     Luis     47
1     Juca     69
```

**Na TextBox:**

```
0 Luis 47
1 Juca 69
```

Como poderia fazer isto ou algo semelhante?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso pode ajudar, explica como preencher e procurar item, basta pegar a parte do loop: http://www.macoratti.net/13/09/vbn_pilv1.htm

crie uma stringBuilder, crie mais tres variaveis tipo string para receber dentro do loop o ID, NOME e IDADE, tudo fora do loop. Dentro do loop você concatena e adiciona no stringBuilder

dim teste as stringBuilder()

teste.Append(Id & " " & NOME & " " & IDADE & "vbVrLf")

Para usar o stringBuilder faz teste.ToString()